# Intercepting calls to defined PHP methods

Tags: php, immutability, value-objects

I'm attempting to create a Trait to make "freezable value objects". (To avoid positional parameters and telescoping constructors.) This means the setters can be used to initialize the object, and then `->freeze()` is called, which makes the object "immutable". The setters will still be there, but when called, they will throw an exception. This can be achieved with a `$this->assertIsWritable();` call at the start of each setter. However I'd like to avoid this (as its easy to forget such a call) and do this check automatically. Is there a way to intercept calls to defined methods?

Not acceptable in the solution:

- Approaches that break type hinting and/or static code analysis
- Dependence on special PHP extensions

I'm using PHP 7.0.

Comment: Something in runkit maybe? Possibly [`method_redefine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-redefine.php). I'm not aware of any way you could do it in a trait though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without modifying the runtime (using extensions such as [Runkit](https://pecl.php.net/package/runkit) or [uopz](https://pecl.php.net/package/uopz) or performing source code transformation on your PHP code while it being loaded (using stream wrapper magic).